# I am using Odoo v10 to do some task but this error is appearing

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-10

```
#model.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields


class fleet_vehicle_direction(models.Model):

    _name = 'fleet.vehicle.direction'
    name = fields.Char(related='vehicle_id.name', string='vehicle name', store=True)
    vehicle_id = fields.Many2one('fleet.vehicle', 'select vehicle name', required=True, help='select vehicle name')
    Quotations_id = fields.One2many('sale.order', 'name', 'Quotation', required=True,help='select  Quotation name')
```

The image of model when install:

[image]

Error when add a new Quotation:

[image]

Comment: Pro-tip: if you notice that someone has edited your question, stop editing. You have rolled back my good edits twice now, and replaced them with poorer quality versions. The question is now in the same mess as when you first asked it, and you're unlikely to get a good answer from it.

Comment: Please post Error in your question, the image you attached doesn't help.

Comment: I have now improved this question considerably. Feel free to edit it further **with improvements**, including the item @KbiR mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in creating your model field which is  `Quotations_id`,the inverse name is so wrong. you can't assign `name` as inverse field because it's already in the sale order and the inverse field should be `Many2one` so to edit that you your field definition must be like that

```
Quotations_id = fields.One2many('sale.order', 'fleet_id', 'Quotation', required=True,help='select  Quotation name')
```

And you have to add the `fleet_id` field in the `sale.order` model as `Many2one` relation like this

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
     _inherit= 'sale.order
     fleet_id = fields.Many2one('fleet.vehicle.direction')
```